# How can I get kernel start time in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I am trying with the following code to get kernel start time but the output of this code is not true.

I want the start time of the kernel function relative to the start time of this program. That is, if we consider the start time of this program as zero time, then what will be the start time of the kernel function.

What is my mistake?

```
//headers
#include <sys/time.h>

//kernel function defined here

int main(){
struct timeval kernelStartTime;

//memcpys and ....

gettimeofday(&kernelStartTime, 0);
MatrixMulCUDA<32><<<matrixMulgrid, matrixMulthreads>>>(C, A, B, dimsA.x, dimsB.x);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

float startTime = (1000000.0 * kernelStartTime.tv_sec + kernelStartTime.tv_usec)/1000.0;

//some codes

printf("kernel start time = %f", startTime);
return 0;
}
```

Output:

kernel start time = 1.63786e+12

Thanks.

Comment: why should 1.6e12 not be the correct answer?  According to the [gettimeofday linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/settimeofday.2.html) that function returns "seconds since the **epoch**".  Do you know what that is?  The epoch seems to be `1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).`.    Your scaling seems to actually be producing a number of milliseconds since the epoch.  That number appears to be in the right ballpark, for the number of milliseconds from 1970 until now.  What value were you expecting?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Crovella. After your comment, I understood what I should do.

Comment: you can also consider using a callback to get the actual kernel start time, when you do not want to use cudaDeviceSynchronize - https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1g74aa9f4b1c2f12d994bf13876a5a2498

Comment: @meh Since you have posted an answer to your own question, please consider also accepting that answer. It is more helpful to the community if questions have accepted answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//headers
#include <sys/time.h>

//kernel function defined here

int main(){
struct timeval kernelStartTime, baseTime;
gettimeofday(&baseTime, 0);

//memcpys and ....

gettimeofday(&kernelStartTime, 0);
MatrixMulCUDA<32><<<matrixMulgrid, matrixMulthreads>>>(C, A, B, dimsA.x, dimsB.x);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

float startTime = (1000000.0 * (kernelStartTime.tv_sec - baseTime.tv_sec) + (kernelStartTime.tv_usec - baseTime.tv_usec))/1000.0;

//some codes

printf("kernel start time = %f", startTime);
return 0;
}
```